# Agrupar resultados con fecha actual

Tags: php, mysql, array, unix

Ejemplo, tengo una consulta `mysql` así

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE fecha >= $time;
```

donde `$time` = semana actual

también tengo un `array` con los días, a los que se le agrupara

`$days = array('Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado', 'Domingo')`

¿Cómo podría hacer para agrupar con `php` los resultados conforme a su día actual?

Ejemplo:

**Todo los post del dia lunes**

```
-Post del dia lunes 1
-Post del dia lunes 2
```

**Todo los post del dia Martes**

```
-Post del dia martes 1
-Post del dia martes 2
```

miércoles, jueves, viernes, sabado domingo....

psd: Agrupar los resultados, de acuerdo a su día con `php`

Comment: ¿A qué se debe la etiqueta `Unix` en la pregunta?

Comment: Alexis has editado tu query a que la fecha sea mayor a la semana actual, entonces no podrás tener más de un lunes, martes, ... Lo cual no es lo mismo que preguntabas en un principio. Por cierto, el campo fecha ¿tiene formato date?

Comment: estoy guardando las fechas en formato UNIX time();

Answer (score 2):

Quizá esto pueda resolver tu problema:

```
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(nombre SEPARATOR '|') as nombres, fecha
    FROM   test_semana
    WHERE  YEARWEEK(`fecha`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
    GROUP BY DAY(fecha)
    ORDER BY fecha;
```

- `GROUP_CONCAT`junto con `GROUP BY DAY(fecha)` te crean un arreglo de los registros de cada día en una columna llamada `nombres`.
- Puedes usar `explode` para leer el valor de  cada registro usando el separador `|`
- `WHERE  YEARWEEK(`fecha`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)` obtiene **de forma automática** los registros de la semana actual.

Aquí puedes ver la doc sobre **[`YEARWEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)**. Y sobre **[`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)**.

---

#### `Ejemplo completo:` [`ver demo`](http://rextester.com/KAT25032)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_semana (
         id SERIAL,
         nombre VARCHAR(50),
         fecha date
       );

 INSERT INTO test_semana (fecha, nombre) VALUES
     ('2017-04-01', 'Pedro'),
     ('2017-04-02', 'Santiago'),
     ('2017-04-03', 'Juan'),
     ('2017-06-25', 'Andrés'),
     ('2017-06-26', 'Felipe'),
     ('2017-06-27', 'Mateo'),
     ('2017-06-27', 'Marcos'),
     ('2017-06-28', 'Ana'),
     ('2017-06-28', 'María'),
     ('2017-06-28', 'José'),
    ('2017-07-20', 'Pablo');



SELECT * FROM test_semana;  


SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(nombre SEPARATOR '|') as nombres, fecha
FROM   test_semana
WHERE  YEARWEEK(`fecha`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
GROUP BY DAY(fecha)
ORDER BY fecha;
```

---

#### `Resultado`

Todos los registros:

```
    id  nombre      fecha
1   1   Pedro       01.04.2017 00:00:00
2   2   Santiago    02.04.2017 00:00:00
3   3   Juan        03.04.2017 00:00:00
4   4   Andrés      25.06.2017 00:00:00
5   5   Felipe      26.06.2017 00:00:00
6   6   Mateo       27.06.2017 00:00:00
7   7   Marcos      27.06.2017 00:00:00
8   8   Ana         28.06.2017 00:00:00
9   9   María       28.06.2017 00:00:00
10  10  José        28.06.2017 00:00:00
11  11  Pablo       20.07.2017 00:00:00
```

Registros filtrados: es lo que interesa

```
    nombres         fecha
1   Felipe          26.06.2017 00:00:00
2   Mateo|Marcos    27.06.2017 00:00:00
3   Ana|María|José  28.06.2017 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Para sacar los post ordenados por la fecha y el día de la semana:

```
SELECT *, WEEKDAY($fecha) AS DAY
FROM post WHERE fecha <= $time
ORDER BY $fecha, WEEKDAY($fecha);
```

Si quieres agruparlos puedes hacer un `GROUP BY` este mismo criterio o usarlo en el `WHERE` para delimitar un/os día/s determinado/s.

Los valores de DAY son los días de 0 a 6 empezando por el lunes.